# Active Admin: Multiple Actions in same column similar to View, Edit, Delete

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I am using active admin gem to have a admin console for my ruby on rails application. I am having a problem where i want to have multiple custom actions to every item on index page just like View,Edit, Delete. But when adding custom action only the last one is displayed instead of all.

```
 index do

   column 'Instructor Name',:user
   column 'Email Address', :email
   column 'Phone Number', :phone
   column 'website', link_to 'google', 'www.google.com' 
   column :bio
   actions defaults: false do |application|
     if application.user.instructor == 2
       button_to  'Disapprove', instructor_deny_user_path(application.user.id), method: :put
     else
       button_to  'Approve', instructor_approve_user_path(application.user.id), method: :put
     end 
     link_to "resume",getresume_instructor_applications_path(id: application.id)
   end 
 end
```

Only resume link is shown instead of Approve/Disprove and resume

What am i doing wrong

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have ActiveAdmin >= 1.0.0.preX, you can do this:

```
   actions defaults: false do |application|
     if application.user.instructor == 2
       action_item  'Disapprove', instructor_deny_user_path(application.user.id), method: :put
     else
       action_item  'Approve', instructor_approve_user_path(application.user.id), method: :put
     end 
     action_item "resume", getresume_instructor_applications_path(id: application.id)
   end
```

If you use a 0.6.x:

```
   actions defaults: false do |application|
     if application.user.instructor == 2
       text_node link_to  'Disapprove', instructor_deny_user_path(application.user.id), method: :put
     else
       text_node link_to  'Approve', instructor_approve_user_path(application.user.id), method: :put
     end 
     link_to "resume", getresume_instructor_applications_path(id: application.id)
   end
```

Comment: Oh Boy inventor him self. you made my day. This works but Disapprove/Approve and resume appears as a word rather that 2 different words separated by space

Comment: Okay i read ActiveAdmin docs got to know about span so just added span to both approve and disprove links

Comment: Even this is an answer

Comment: In v1.3, you need to use `item` instead of `action_item`, and include the class `member_link` to add the extra space between the links: https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/issues/53

Answer (score 1):

For v1.3 the solution

```
   actions defaults: false do |application|
     if application.user.instructor == 2
       item  'Disapprove', instructor_deny_user_path(application.user.id), method: :put
     else
       item  'Approve', instructor_approve_user_path(application.user.id), method: :put
     end 
     item "resume", getresume_instructor_applications_path(id: application.id)
   end
```

is what worked for me - thanks to @littleforest 's comment

You can also add `, class: "member_link"` for the spacing

Answer (score 0):

Try put your approve/disapprove links in columns like this,

```
column 'action' do |application|
  application.user.instructor == 2 ? button_to  'Disapprove', instructor_deny_user_path(application.user.id), method: :put :  button_to  'Approve', instructor_approve_user_path(application.user.id), method: :put
end
```

And Default link for resume as it is.

```
actions defaults: false do |application|
  link_to "resume",getresume_instructor_applications_path(id: application.id)
end
```

Comment: Yo Worked. Thanks mate